# Jboss EAP 6 module hot deployment

Tags: java, spring, jboss6.x

I am working with Jboss EAP 6.4 domain architecture. My plan is to bundle all the resource property files as external module and define a deployment structure to add them to the class path. This is perfectly working fine, but the changes made during run time is not detecting by the server, needs a jvm restart. Is there any way we can make this hot deployment?

Answer (score 1):

May be the concept is to store the properties value on memory and restore periodically when property file has changed. Please refer to https://www.google.com/amp/s/howtodoinjava.com/java7/auto-reload-of-configuration-when-any-change-happen/amp/

Comment: Thanks, but I am not expecting an application level change here. I would love to hear a jboss domain ootb configuration for reloading.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to know that hot deployment is not recommended in Production environments for JBoss EAP. However, this is feasible by using "exploded deployments" (file system based deployments).